# JQuery UI DatePicker Change Date to Text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have added a JQuery UI datepicker to my website and would like to remove the text shown e.g. the date to show "Select Date..." is this possible if so how? As I have tried to alter this in the javascript with no luck.

Comment: So you never want to show the user the date they've selected?

Comment: Yes and then it should be changed to "Select Date..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple methods.

1) Make the text "invisible" in CSS by setting the color to white

```
#datepicker{
   color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

2) Catching the datepicker event (onSelect), saving the date in a variable / hidden input and removing the value from the datepicker element

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
        onSelect: function(date) {
            // Save date in variable
            var datevariable = date;

            // Or save the date in a hidden input field
            $('#hidden-input').val(date);

            // Clear the input of the datepicker
            $('#datepicker').val('Select date...');
        }
    });
});
```

3) Using a seperate element or icon as trigger to activate the datepicker, and making the actual input element invisible by setting display: none.

Comment: Hi this may sound stupid, but where would I alter the datepicker event? As in which javascript? Would it be the one in the H-Query UI or my custom javascript

Comment: Thanks sorry for the delay!